# UnClickAble TouchableHighlight

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, ecmascript-6

I got this code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.MyClick = this.MyClick.bind(this)
}
MyClick() {
  alert('ohoho')
};
AnyRequest = () => {
    if(this.state.Array.length > 0 && this.state.Loaded === true){
        return this.state.Array.map(function(Data){
            return(
              <View>
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={this.MyClick}>
                    <Icon name="check" size={30} color="#2eb82e" />
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>

            );
        });
    }
};
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. First when I used `MyClick = () =>` instead of binding function in the constructor it was saying undefined is not an object. As soon as I bound my function in the constructor it doesn't show error anymore but it doesn't seem like a `TouchableHighlight` button. Even `underlayColor` doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show me the full contents of the class?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tu01zcfL/

Comment: Does the `TouchableHighlight` or its children (`Icon`) render at all? Does anything print to the console if you do: `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={() => { console.log('test'); }}>`

Comment: @MichaelCheng Icon is rendered normally. That example what you wrote `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={() => { console.log('test'); }}>` works fine but this `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={this.MyClick}>` doesn't. And I can write complete function only this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. Problem wasn't in onPress function but in map function. As soon as I was creating new function it created a new scope which means `this` wasn't referring to `AnyRequest` function anymore. Finally ES6 arrows fixed it.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.MyClick = this.MyClick.bind(this)
}
MyClick() {
alert('ohoho')
};
AnyRequest = () => {
if(this.state.Array.length > 0 && this.state.Loaded === true){
    return this.state.Array.map((Data) => (
          <View>
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={() => 
                this.MyClick();
            }}>
                <Icon name="check" size={30} color="#2eb82e" />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        ));
      }
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so from the comments, we can conclude that this the `TouchableHighlight` is indeed clickable. It's just your syntax for `onPress` that is incorrect. This is a very common mistake for developers without much experience in binding and ES6 syntax. There are [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch/34361380) that cover this already so I won't go into depth on it. Instead, I'll point out the two common ways you can correct define `onPress` in React Native (there are also [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483825/touchablehighlight-press-error) existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527230/how-can-i-call-method-from-onpress-on-alert-function-react-native) for this but they are only partially related):

The `onPress` prop of `TouchableHighlight` expects a function to be passed to it. So whatever is between the `{ }` needs to be a function. The **first way** to do this is with arrow syntax which I suspect you did incorrectly:

```
MyClick = () => {
  alert('ohoho')
};

// ... later on ...

<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ccc" onPress={this.MyClick}>
  <Icon name="check" size={30} color="#2eb82e" />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

*Note the `this.` as it's needed to correctly reference the right variable.*

The **second way** is to bind the method as you're doing but then actually call it in a function that you pass to `onPress` like so:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.MyClick = this.MyClick.bind(this);
}

MyClick() {
  alert('ohoho');
};

// ... later on ...

<TouchableHighlight
  underlayColor="#ccc"
  onPress={() => {
    this.MyClick();
  }}
>
  <Icon name="check" size={30} color="#2eb82e" />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

*Note how you are defining an arrow function inside the `{ }` and then actually calling `MyClick` inside that function.*

If you don't understand the difference or make many mistakes like this, then I suggest brushing up on ES6 and ES7 as that is almost a requirement for writing React Native code. There are [many resources](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com) online to help with this.